# How can I make a link to invoke the download dialog box rather than it being shown

Tags: html

How can I modify

```
<a href="someimage">Download this</a>
```

in order to invoke the download dialog box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could send a

```
Content-disposition: attachment; filename=someimage.jpg
```

HTTP header.

Answer (score 0):

Instruct the server to send it with a generic binary MIME type - binary/octet-stream is good for this. Standards conforming browsers will then just download it.

Comment: is that something that only can be done by modifying mime types or javascript can also do it?